# that if X is finite, then it is first countable

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if X is finite, then it is first countable.
My solution:
If X is finite then the largest topology on X is the discrete topology
And there are a local base at all point in X if the topology is the discrete 
Since X is finite then the subset in the discrete topology is finite and countable
Then there is a countable local base at each point of X
Therefore it is first countable.
Is it true or false? And what the true solution?

Comment: There are only finitely many open sets. So any collection of open sets is countable.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is finite, then so is the topology $\mathcal{T}_X$ (as a subset of $\mathscr{P}(X)$).

So for every point $\mathcal{B}_x = \{O \in \mathcal{T}_X: x \in O\}$ is by definition a local base for $x$ and finite (so certainly at most countable, as is required) as a subset of $\mathcal{T}_X$.

It's not the case that $X$ needs to be discrete (only if it's $T_1$) for consider the indiscrete and the Sierpinski topology, e.g.. But we *can* always (like in the discrete topology) find a local base for $x$ of size $1$, using that finite intersections of open sets are open: every $x$ in a space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ with a finite topology has a minimal open set $O_x = \bigcap \{O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O\}$, and $\{O_x\}$ is a local base at $x$ of size $1$.